# UWP change foreground color of TextBox with Binding

Tags: uwp

I have this code:

```
   <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Date}"
                                       />
```

I want to change this TextBox color as well with Binding.

I tried the following:

```
  public class ArticleItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush ColorBrush;
    }
```

and tried to bind ColorBrush, but the foreground color wont change.

```
                    list.Items.Add(new ArticleItem() { Title = item.Title.Text, Date = item.PublishedDate.ToString(), ColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Url = item.Links[0].Uri.ToString()});
```

in XML:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Date}" Foreground="{Binding ColorBrush}"
                                       />
```

Comment: What type is your `list` variable? It has to be `ObservableCollection`

Comment: @Alamakanambra it is a ItemsControl, the title works but color doesnt, only observablecollection can change color?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Can you post rest of your xaml?

Comment: Have you solved your question by my following solution?

Answer (score 0):

Binding is bind to a property, not a field. You need to define your ColorBrush as a property.

```
public class ArticleItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush ColorBrush { get; set; }
}
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ArticleItem> list { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        list = new ObservableCollection<ArticleItem>();
        list.Add(new ArticleItem() { Title = "title1", ColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Date = DateTime.Now.ToString() });
        list.Add(new ArticleItem() { Title = "title2", ColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), Date = DateTime.Now.ToString() });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Date}" Foreground="{Binding ColorBrush}"></TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```